# Check if row already exists stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

So I have this MySQL Stored Procedure, but how do I check if the row already exists?

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`edmetrics`@`%` PROCEDURE `CreateTestJob`(JobLink varchar(300), StartTime datetime, Endtime datetime, Owner_info varchar(45), Engine_info varchar(100), TestSuiteId INT, TestSuiteCollectionId INT, Finished varchar(45), JenkinsBuild INT(100), JenkinsJobName varchar(100))
BEGIN

    IF TestSuiteId = '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteId = null;
    END IF;
    
    IF TestSuiteCollectionId = '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteCollectionId = null;
    END IF;
    
    IF TestSuiteCollectionId != '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteId = null;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO TestJob (`id`,`JobLink`,`StartTime`,`Endtime`,`Owner`,`Engine`,`TestSuiteId`,`TestSuiteCollectionId`,`Finished`,`JenkinsBuild`,`JenkinsJobName`) 
    VALUES (NULL, JobLink, StartTime, Endtime, Owner_info, Engine_info, TestSuiteId, TestSuiteCollectionId, Finished, JenkinsBuild, JenkinsJobName);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LastInsertId;
  
  
END
```

So as suggested I should use `if exists` BUT a variable is empty then its set to null and if not then there is a variable. but this makes it a bit harder since this wont work:

```sql
BEGIN
    declare return_id int;
    
    IF TestSuiteId = '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteId = null;
    END IF;
    
    IF TestSuiteCollectionId = '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteCollectionId = null;
    END IF;
    
    IF TestSuiteCollectionId != '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteId = null;
    END IF;
    
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT 
        `JobLink`,
        `StartTime`,
        `Endtime`,
        `Owner`,
        `Engine`,
        `TestSuiteId`,
        `TestSuiteCollectionId`,
        `Finished`,
        `JenkinsBuild`,
        `JenkinsJobName`
        FROM
            testreportingdebug.testjob
        WHERE
            `JobLink` = JobLink
                AND `StartTime` = StartTime
                AND `Endtime` = Endtime
                AND `Owner` = Owner_info
                AND `Engine` = Engine_info
                AND `TestSuiteId` = TestSuiteId
                AND `TestSuiteCollectionId` = TestSuiteCollectionId
                AND `Finished` = Finished
                AND `JenkinsBuild` = JenkinsBuild
                AND `JenkinsJobName` = JenkinsJobName LIMIT 1))
    THEN
        SET return_id = -1;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO TestJob (`id`,`JobLink`,`StartTime`,`Endtime`,`Owner`,`Engine`,`TestSuiteId`,`TestSuiteCollectionId`,`Finished`,`JenkinsBuild`,`JenkinsJobName`) 
        VALUES (NULL, JobLink, StartTime, Endtime, Owner_info, Engine_info, TestSuiteId, TestSuiteCollectionId, Finished, JenkinsBuild, JenkinsJobName);
        SET return_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END IF;
    
    SELECT return_id AS LastInsertId;
    
END
```

This will only work if all variables is set, if one or more is `null` then it doesn't work. since you cant say `varaible = null` but only `variable is null` and the other way around. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use IF_EXIST command to check.

thank you.

Comment: thanks, but I've made a edit to my question, because I have some problems with this solution, since I have strings in some cases and null variables in other cases